# Does Win10 System Restore slowdown entire OS after each restore?

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

Recently I needed to perform a System Restore to a manual point made before an update. What I've updated is Java, that I've uninstalled and then updated, and GeForce drivers, both created me some problems not related to OS (Java was somewhat not compatible with a program that I use and GeForce resetted my setting and added unwanted things).

So I've decided to rollback my system to a previous restore point, created just before this updates, that solved this problems.

What I've found after this rollback is an increased use of CPU and a little slowdown when opening programs.

**My question is:**
Does Win10 System Restore slowdown entire OS after each restore?

p.s. PC is a top level bought 2 month ago with an SSD and recently installed OS with very few and essential programs installed. So this can't be related to HW.

Answer (score -1):

All versions of windows slow down over time. Using windows tools to "rollback" is unlikely to actually DO that, rather it will just break and re-link things to give the appearance of it.
Your best bet for backups/security/archives is to do a clean install on a zeroed drive, install drivers, update system, install known good programs, then IMAGE the partition. If you need to restore for any reason, wipe the partition and reload the image to it.